# Problem running a VMware VM created under Fusion on Mac under VMware Server on Linux

Tags: linux, mac-osx, vmware-fusion

Hopefully the question says it all; materials I've found on the web suggest I should be able to copy my VM from OSX to Linux.  I copied all the VM files from OSX to Linux, but when I try to open my VM using "Open existing virtual machine", it seems to kill the VMware server web console.  After restarting the console, the import job for the new VM has disappeared.

Here are my version details:

VMware Fusion 2.0.6 on OSX 10.6 (Snow Leopard 64-bit)

VMware Server 2.0 on Fedora 11 (64-bit)

Has anyone else had success with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with VMware Player instead of Server on my Linux host, and was able to figure out the cause of the problem:

The virtual machine you are attempting to restore is using the NX/ED CPU feature, but your host does not support it.

It doesn't look as if there is any way around this short of recreating the VVM on the Linux host.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  I've even done it a few times, both directions.  I didn't have to do anything special that I remember.

Comment: Thanks - I edited the question header to make it clearer that I'm having a problem.